# No Sound after Upgrade to Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After the upgrade to 14.04 I can't hear anything anymore. The basic troubleshooting looks good, but with `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` nothing is to hear.

```
# lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 21f6
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at f2630000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
root@W530:/home/ufriebe# aplay -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0

#aplay -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Show the output of `amixer scontents`. (And please use `<pre>`.)

Comment: I fixed it with the help of  "pavucontrol". For some reasons Configuration->InternalAudio was set to "Dummy device".
I changed the config back to "AnalogStereoDuplex". Now Loudspeaker and headphones are working again. This Link is really helpful:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the help of "pavucontrol".
For some reasons Configuration->Internal Audio was set to "Dummy device". I changed the config back to "Analog Stereo Duplex". Now Loudspeaker and headphones are working again.
This Link is really helpful:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting